# Disable animation for specific element

Tags: jquery

How can I disable/suppress animation for specific element? Globally this is done with `$.fx.off = true`. How to do this "locally"?.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to turn off animation at the element level. You would need to check the target element manually before making the call to whatever animation method you're using.

Comment: Interesting idea for a jQuery plugin, none the less.